# How can I get document hash from documentum using DQL?

Tags: documentum, opentext, documentum-dql, dctm

Using DQMan or Document Admistrator, what's DQL statement to get hash of document in DCTM?

Select ... ?

If it's not possible how can I get it?

(I know exactly which is the document, r_chronicle_id, r_object_id, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no field representing a document hash, but take a look in the dmr_content object table. It should be here if there is one (I haven't checked I several years).
Alternatively you would have to get it with API - either there is a method or you should do it yourself. Take a look in the api guide.

Edit: just searched the object reference guide. Turns out that there is a field in dmr_content. It's called r_content_hash.
Have a look at it to see if your docbase fulfills requirements to have this field populated. Maybe you're in luck ;-)

Comment: ok, found what you're talking about "...Used only if the server is installed  with a Content storage Services license, this property configures hash generation for content files in the storage area... " etc... ...Anyway: "select r_content_hash from sg_XXX;" returns "[DM_QUERY_E_NOT_ATTRIBUTE]error - You have specified an invalid attribute name (r_content_hash).".  I'm sure we have hash generation enabled. Using Java API we can retrieve it after document generation. I'd like to access this information using some DQL or some tool at any time. I'd prefear not to write a new piece of sw...